# What I did in my weekend with Riley

Tags: riddle, word

Based on a true story. Mine.

> It was a sunny weekend, so I really just wanted to go to my prefix,
>   But with all the outstanding work around the house I spent more time in my suffix.
>   Thanks to my infix though, my tools could remove a lot of the manual labour otherwise required.
>   The weekend is over, this riddle is now my whole.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's got to be

> PUBLISHED.

*It was a sunny weekend, so I really just wanted to go to my prefix,*

> You wanted to go to the PUB.

*But with all the outstanding work around the house I spent more time in my suffix.*

> You spent most of the time in your SHED.

*Thanks to my infix though, my tools could remove a lot of the manual labour otherwise required.*

> Your tools are powered by LI or LIB batteries (thanks @SteveV for getting this).

*The weekend is over, this riddle is now my whole.*

> The riddle is PUBLISHED.

Comment: Nice one - the overall answer is correct as is most of your points. Only thing a bit skew is the infix (which admittedly was a bit shoehorned). Perhaps as a clue: rot13(nyy zl cbjre gbbyf ner pbeqyrff)

Comment: i thought that, but i just couldn't make the infix work!  but you're right, it must be those rot13(yv onggrevrf)

Comment: @SteveV I guess the suffix was the starting point for both of us, as it works well with line 2 and also looks like it could end a word for line 4. But your word applies to the *weekend* and not the *riddle*. (I did see your answer before posting mine, but I'd already thought of the suffix independently, hence why I didn't add credit to you for that part. Hope you don't mind.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor of course not, good solve!!

Comment: Aha, just saw your comment edit with the infix. Nice one. There was me looking up for brands like DeWalt and Bosch :-D

Comment: Yep, nailed it now :)

Answer (score 7):

I will guess

> vanished

Because
It was a sunny weekend, so I really just wanted to go to my prefix

> You wanted to go to your VAN

But with all the outstanding work around the house I spent more time in my suffix

> You were stuck in your [work]SHED

Thanks to my infix though, my tools could remove a lot of the manual labour otherwise required.

> Thanks to I, which is the symbol for electric current, which runs your power tools

The weekend is over, this riddle is now my whole.

> after all your work, your weekend has VANISHED

Comment: Nice answer - but I'm afraid not quite what I'm after (I don't have a van) but not completely inaccurate for a couple of points. +1